# How can I mock sweetalert and how do i make it return true on angular test

Tags: angular, testing, sweetalert2

I want to write angular test on my typescript. My typescript code is like that

```
swal({
      title: "ONAY",
      text: `Delete this row?`,
      type: "warning",
      showConfirmButton: true,
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: "Delete",
      cancelButtonText: "Not Delete",
      confirmButtonColor: "#ef5350"
    }).then(isConfirm => {
   if (isConfirm.value != null && isConfirm.value) {
   //DO SOMETHING
}
    });
```

I want to write test on //DO SOMETHING expression but I don't reach this block because of sweetalert confirm window.

How can I mock sweetalert and how do i make it return true?

Comment: any progress on this one?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to mock Swal in my test suite.

You would need to mock and resolve the sweetalert fire function

```
jest.mock("sweetalert2", () => ({
   fire: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ isConfirmed: true }),
}));
```

Then flush the promise in the test.

```
expect(Swal.fire).toBeCalled();
await flushPromises();
expect(something).toBeTruthy();
```

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Previously I mocked the `highcharts` module, then I came up with an idea that doing the same for `sweetalert2` and it works ok.

1. create  a  folder named `__mock__` in `src` folder
2. create a file `<moduleToMock>.js`

> Eg: sweetalert2.js

3. put this content into file created at step 2

```
const sweetalert2 = jest.genMockFromModule('sweetalert2');
sweetalert2.fire = jest.fn();
module.exports = sweetalert2;
```

Then in test:

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
...
...
...
test((=>{
   Swal.fire.mockResolvedValue({ value: something });
))
```

---

Ref: https://gist.github.com/alfonsomunozpomer/2bcbbb89bcdb8e5b8ed7070654779d99